# Como descomponer una cifra introducida por el usuario en los dígitos o cifras que lo componen y sumarlos en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supongamos que el usuario coloca un valor de 4 cifras, ejemplo: 2134, como descompongo ese valor para poder sumar el 2+1+3+4?

Intente hacerlo por mi cuenta e investigar, pero soy novato aun y necesito ayuda.

Comment: Hola, como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas. Pero es necesario mostrar lo que has investigado para poder ser ayudado en StackOverflow. Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el OP está pidiendo que se le haga un ejercicio de clase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se realiza con un bucle en el que en cada ciclo:

- Se obtiene la ultima cifra del numero con el operador de residuo %
- Se suma el digito obtenido en un acumulador (**suma**)
- Se reduce el numero quitando la ultima cifra, dividiéndolo en 10

El codigo sería como sigue:

```
numero = int(input("Ingrese en numero:"))
tmpnumero=numero
dig=int(0)
suma=0;
while(tmpnumero!=0):
    dig=int(tmpnumero % 10)
    suma+=dig
    tmpnumero=int(tmpnumero/10)
print("La suma de los digitos de ",numero," es ",suma)
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución, usando comprensión de listas:

```
val = "1234"
resultado=sum(int(digito) for digito in val)
```

Cuando aplicas un `for` a un string, recorres las caracteres del string, que me retornan en la variable `digito`. Los conviertes a entero uno a uno con `int()`, generando una lista de valores, los que se suman con `sum`.